# Create a new table in mySQL with specific options

Tags: mysql, flask

I just began learning mySQL and I was wondering what was the query for this subject:

```
task table
•task_id (mandatory not null)
•title (mandatory not null)
•begin (optional value when creating a task, current date by default)
•end (optional value when creating a task, empty by default)
•status (not started by default /in progress/done)
```

I've tried this for now:

```
CREATE TABLE task (
    -> task_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    -> title VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    -> begin ???,
    ->end ???,
    ->status (I guess I need an ENUM)
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah you are almost there.

begin has to be defined as DATE,  but CURRENT_DATE only works in MySQL 8

Status must be defined as ENUM

You must add to task_id the PRIMARY KEY, else MySQL doesn't like it

```
CREATE TABLE task (
     task_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
     title VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    begin DATE DEFAULT (CURRENT_DATE),
    end DATE DEFAULT NULL,
    Status  ENUM('not started', 'in progress', 'done') DEFAULT 'not started'    
)
```

Comment: A slightly more flexible solution (some frameworks don't like `enum` type) may be to change `status` to `status_id` and then create a separate lookup table to store the `status_id`s and `status` values.

Comment: he is doing a tutorial, the normalizing will probably come later

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, guys ! Have a nice day and be safe ;)

Comment: My bad @nbk, I forget to accept ! Thanks for the help.